# Angularjs dataTable stateSave not woking on change routes

Tags: angularjs, datatable, local-storage, angular-datatables, state-saving

I'm using AngularJS datatable and enable save state with `.withOption('stateSave', true)`.

when I refresh the page, everything works fine But when I change routes, and came back, `stateSave` not working.

---

**I found that**, At each route change, datatable create a `localStorage` to save current table state with difference `key`! so when change route, saveState not working.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add an attribute id into the table.
And add the following code into your angularjs controller

```
$scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withOption('stateSave', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `id` attribute to the `<table>` element, like `<table id="xxx" datatable>`.